# Why isn't Levenshtein.distance returning anything?

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

I have the following python function:

```
import Levenshtein

SENTINEL = -1

def findClosestMatch(sampleElemList, convertElem, error):
    matchIndividualElem = False
    lowestLevDistance = SENTINEL
    closestMatchingString = ''
    for sampleElem in sampleElemList:
            if sampleElem.text == convertElem.text:
                    matchIndividualElem = True
                    break
            sampleDistance = Levenshtein.distance(sampleElem.text, convertElem.text)
            if sampleDistance < lowestLevDistance or lowestLevDistance == SENTINEL:
                    lowestLevDistance = sampleDistance
                    closestMatchingString = sampleElem.text
    if matchIndividualElem == False and convertElem.text != None:
            safeErrString = convertElem.text.encode('utf-8')
            error.write('The following text could not be matched: \'' + safeErrString + '\'. The closest text is: ' + closestMatchingString + \
                    ' with a Levenshtein distance of ' + str(lowestLevDistance) +  '.\n\n')
            return 1
    return 0;
```

I've installed a Levenshtein python package from the command line:

```
sudo pip install python-Levenshtein
```

This function is included in a program, which had previously indicated good functionality. It returns either a one or a zero to add to a total of mismatches found in the list thus far.

The program compiles without warnings, and the rest of the program acts as it is supposed to do. However, the error file always reads: 'The following text could not be matched: '' with a Levenshtein distance of -1.

The function should always output something, so long as an element is present in 'sampleElemList', and I know this to be true. Is this a problem with how I've invoked the library? Is it an issue with installation? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: I also had problems with the Python-Levenshtein package in an application I built, and so I just found a public domain implementation of it and put it in a utility module. If you don't need the extra functions in the package, I recommend doing the same. You can find the source code for it (public domain) [here](http://hetland.org/coding/python/levenshtein.py).

Comment: Can you show what input you're feeding it when you get the undesired output? You might try using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Distance/ (`sudo pip install distance`) instead, or writing your own Levenshtein distance function.

Comment: It is likely the usage/function has a bug.. and needs further diagnosis. The message about the text of '' should probably be heeded.

Comment: Also note that this line: `if sampleDistance < lowestLevDistance or lowestLevDistance == SENTINEL:` will initially evaluate as `True`, because at the top you set `lowestLevDistance` to `SENTINEL`.